# Need Help Speeding Up a SQL Server Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that creates quite a few temp tables in memory. I have the following query which takes an extremely long time to run (7 minutes).

```
select 
  a.DEPT,
  a.DIV,
  a.PART,
convert(datetime,convert(varchar(2),datepart("mm",a.Release_Date))+'/1/'+ convert(varchar(4),datepart("yyyy",a.Release_Date)),101) as rptng_mnth
from @tmpReportData3 a
where not exists
(select distinct DEPT,DIV,PART from @tmpReportData4 b
where a.DEPT = b.DEPT and a.DIV = b.DIV and a.PART = b.PART)
order by rptng_mnth
```

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan  look at the execution plan, create indexes, etc...

Comment: you don't needs the distinct in the subquery. Also check if the slow part is due the table variables creation. Last check mem pressure issues and you cna test using temp tables instead variables

Comment: did you check the execution plan where you spend most of the time? and its hard to help you if you don't tell about count of rows, unique, primary keys

Comment: 1) your using a subselect where a left join would probably be more appropriate (LEFT JOIN b ON <your existing conditions> WHERE b.dept IS NULL.
2) Make sure your two tables are indexed by the 3 columns you are joining on and by the column you're ordering by.

Comment: Let me try to answer the questions:

Comment: Let me try to answer the questions:1. I can't change or test the plan because I don't have access to SQL Agent. 2. The whole SP starts off by reading a single table and then creating multiple temp tables in memory. The original table is about 100K rows. 3. How do you do the LEFT JOIN...WHERE IS NULL when you need to match multiple columns? Would it be: LJ a.1=b.1, a.2=b.2, a.3=b.3 Where <just one of the columns IS NULL>???

Comment: Does it actually use a lot of table _variables_ instead of temporary tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query, with the unnecessary `select distinct` removed from the subquery:

```
select a.DEPT, a.DIV, a.PART,
       convert(datetime,convert(varchar(2),datepart("mm",a.Release_Date))+'/1/'+ convert(varchar(4),datepart("yyyy",a.Release_Date)),101) as rptng_mnth
from @tmpReportData3 a
where not exists (select DEPT, DIV, PART
                  from @tmpReportData4 b
                  where a.DEPT = b.DEPT and a.DIV = b.DIV and a.PART = b.PART
                 )
order by rptng_mnth;
```

Your performance problem is probably caused by the `not exists`.  Writing the query using `left join` might provide some benefit.  But, the easiest approach is to switch from using a table variable to a temporary table, `#tmpReportData4`.  Then add an index on the temporary table:  `#tmpReportData4(dept, div, part)`.

Comment: Using temp table instead of table variable, and adding in an index dropped the execution time down to milliseconds. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: @FlyFish . . . From 7 minutes to 1 second, so that's better than 99.7% improvement.  Cool.

Answer (score 1):

A good start would be to change the "not in" to a left join.

You might also consider using "#" (rather than "@") temp tables, because you can index #-tables.

Can you include the complete stored procedure?

```
select 
  a.DEPT
 ,a.DIV
 ,a.PART
 ,convert(datetime,convert(varchar(2),datepart("mm",a.Release_Date))+'/1/'+ convert(varchar(4),datepart("yyyy",a.Release_Date)),101) as rptng_mnth
from
  @tmpReportData3 a
  left join @tmpReportData4 b on b.dept = a.dept and a.div = b.div and a.part = b.part
where b.dept is null
order by
  a.rptng_mnth
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-create the sp, but no use any temp table, no use cursors.. that works for me. Also you can post your whole sp code. :)